# PDO UPDATE statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

I have a basic PDO Update Statement which is not working.
I can't find why...Can anybody help me ?

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $login, $mdp);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$requete=$conn->prepare("UPDATE eleves
                            SET id_ecole = ?,
                            id_classe = ?,
                            id_eleve = ?,
                            nom = ?,
                            prenom = ?,
                            date_naiss = ?,
                            tel = ?,
                            mail = ?,
                            sortie = ?,
                            photo = ?,
                            cantine = ?,
                            religion = ?
                            WHERE (id_ecole = $id_ecole 
                                AND id_classe = $id_classe 
                                AND id_eleve = $id_eleve);");
$requete->execute(array($id_ecole, $id_classe, $id_eleve, 
                        $nom, $prenom, $date_naiss, $tel, 
                        $mail, $sortie, $photo, $cantine, 
                        $religion));
```

The table "eleves" contains an additional column which acts as an auto-increment key

Note that the following query works well :

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $login, $mdp);

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$requete=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO eleves (id_ecole, id_classe, 
                            id_eleve, nom, prenom, date_naiss, 
                            tel, mail, sortie, photo, cantine, religion)    
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
$requete->execute(array($id_ecole, $id_classe, $id_eleve, $nom, 
                        $prenom, $date_naiss, $tel, $mail, 
                        $sortie, $photo, $cantine, $religion));
```

Thank you !

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: You clearly know how to use parametrized queries? Why aren't you using parameters in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: WHY did you not use parameters for ALL the query including the WHERE clause

Comment: Why are you setting the `id_ecole`, `id_classe`, and `id_eleve` columns to the same values that they already have?

Comment: @RiggsFolly : You're right but i am the only user here... I will change that anyway thanks for the advice !

Comment: @Barmar humm you're right that's pretty dumb ! But the original problem stay the same.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with the query. Are you sure the row with those IDs already exists?

Comment: @Barmar : yeah i am sur that the row with those IDs exist.

Comment: Then it should work. Note that `id_eleve` is enough to uniquely specify the row, since it's the primary key.

Comment: @Barmar id_eleve is not the primary key. I can have 2 identical id_eleve in different "classe". And i can have 2 identical id_classe in different "ecole". That's why the primary key is a auto increment value.

Comment: You say it's "not working" but that's not clear. Is there an exception? If so, what is the message returned in the exception? Does the exception occur on `prepare()` or `execute()`? Or is there no exception but the update doesn't affect any rows? Or it affects the wrong rows, or sets the wrong values? Please describe what "not working" means in this case.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood and thought that `id_eleve` was the auto increment column for the `eleves` table. Usually a column named `id_XXX` or `XXX_id` is the PK of the table `XXX`.

Comment: What are the values of `$id_ecole`, `$id_classe`, and `$id_eleve` when you format the UPDATE statement? Are you sure they contain valid values and are not blank or null?

Comment: @BillKarwin "Not working" in this case = the treatment does nothing and i have 0 exception... I will ads echo on $id_ecole, $id_classe and $id_eleve

Comment: The problem is solved... i had a space in the php name... My bad ! Thank you for your help !